# Use Regex to replace HREFs

Tags: .net, regex, replace, href

I have html email that I would like to track click activity. I need to update all hrefs within the email to point back to my server where they can be logged and redirected. Is there an easy way to do this globally using .Net regex?

```
<a href="http://abc.com">ABC</a>
```

becomes

```
<a href="http://mydomain.com?uid=123&url=http:/abc.com>ABC</a>
```

Comment: Is the email data being generated by someone from a form field? So you want to change it after they post the data to the server?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following code

```
public string ReplaceLinks(string emailSource) {
    string resultString = null;
    try {
        resultString = Regex.Replace(emailSource, "(<a href=\")(htt)", new MatchEvaluator(ComputeReplacement));
    } catch (ArgumentException ex) {
        // Syntax error in the regular expression
    }
    return resultString;
}

public String ComputeReplacement(Match m) {
    // You can vary the replacement text for each match on-the-fly
    return "$1http://mydomain.com?uid=123&url=$2";
}
```

Comment: I do not understand why @Oded 's solution is not the accepted one, it's not only clearer but makes more sense

Answer (score 2):

Do not use a RegEx to parse HTML - it is not a regular language. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for some compelling demonstrations.

Use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the HTML and replace the URLs.